# Ios google maps закрывает все остальные элементы

Tags: google-maps, xcode, google-maps-api, ios, objective-c

Добавил гугл карты (просто вставил код в файл .m), карты отражаются нормально, но больше ничего не получается добавить, в частности nav bar. Оказалось, что всё остальное отражается под картой - как это исправить?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
UINavigationBar *navbar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
//do something like background color, title, etc you self
[self.view addSubview:navbar];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

[GMSServices provideAPIKey:
```

Comment: Если Вы убираете карту, навбар виден на котроллере?

Comment: @AlexThumb  в том то и дело, что виден

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону:

```
– insertSubview:atIndex:
– insertSubview:aboveSubview:
– insertSubview:belowSubview:
– exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:
```

Это позволит вставить вид в правильное место иерархии.

Или добавляйте в правильной последовательности.